# Should systemctl show output when start/stop fails?

Tags: service, systemd, systemctl

I've googled every variation of this question I can think of, but I'm just getting questions about failed services, not about how systemctl treats them. I have a service that I've been running as an init.d script. We're using systemctl now, fine. I created a service file that's a lightly modified version of the file automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator. For ExecStart and ExecStop, it calls a bash script that returns 0 if the start/stop was successful, and non-zero if it was not.

I understand that there's no output from "systemctl start/stop" if it was successful. But I also don't get any output if either of the calls failed. The return code of the systemctl start/stop command is always 0 even if the return code of the source script is not. It's very clear it did fail because it shows as failed when I run the status command.

Is that expected behavior? Should it not give any indication that something failed unless you run a separate status command? And if that's not how it should behave, how can I make it indicate that a failure occurred?

Service file below.

```
[Unit]
SourcePath=/my/service/script.sh

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/my/service/script.sh start
ExecStop=/my/service/script.sh stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine here, CentOS 7.  Maybe double check that script.sh is really returning non zero?

```
$pwd
/etc/systemd/system
$cat me.service
[Unit]

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/die.sh
$cat die.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "dying"
exit 1
$sudo systemctl start me
Job for me.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status me.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
$sudo systemctl status me.service
● me.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/me.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-09-12 17:55:02 GMT; 8s ago
  Process: 19758 ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/die.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 12 17:55:02 dpsdev-wkr01 systemd[1]: Starting me.service...
Sep 12 17:55:02 dpsdev-wkr01 die.sh[19758]: dying
Sep 12 17:55:02 dpsdev-wkr01 systemd[1]: me.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 12 17:55:02 dpsdev-wkr01 systemd[1]: Failed to start me.service.
Sep 12 17:55:02 dpsdev-wkr01 systemd[1]: Unit me.service entered failed state.
Sep 12 17:55:02 dpsdev-wkr01 systemd[1]: me.service failed.
```